# Composite primary key with not primitive attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, composite-primary-key

I am new to Java and Hibernate. I've got problem with composite key. I am trying to do something like that:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    int id;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Id
    int id;
}


@Entity
class C {
    @EmbeddedId
    C_PK c_pk;
}

@Embeddable
class C_PK {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

When I perform

```
...
session.save(c);
...
```

Then exception is thrown that type of A and B cannot be inserted into database. Is it possible to somehow tell hibernate to don't save the A object but only the A id? Is my approach absolutely wrong and should I just use primitive data types at C_PK class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a `@ManyToOne` (or `OneToOne`) with join columns on the A and B references in C_PK.

```
@Embeddable
class C_PK {
    @ManyToOne
    A a;
    @ManyToOne
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Please read section 2.2.3.2 - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177.  "While not supported in JPA, Hibernate lets you place your association directly in the embedded id component (instead of having to use the @MapsId annotation)."

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it really looked improper. I'll revert my unjust vote once you edit the answer.

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:`